# WSO2 : "Error connecting to Back end" when testing Integration Solution

Tags: kubernetes, wso2-api-manager, wso2

**Hello everyone,**

I deployed WSO2 APIM on a kubernetes cluster which includes the micro integrator, and I used Integration Studio locally to develop my first integration solution.

**I followed these steps:**

- Configured the service catalog in Integration Studio using the ingress address of the APIM
- The service appears inside the services tab
- I created an API out of that service

**Error** : When I try testing the API I get the following error "Error Connecting to Back end"

I think the service url may be the problem, I tried using the ingress address for the **Micro Integrator** but it didn't work

**The following is my configuration:**

- metadata.yaml file

```
---
key: "HelloWorld-1.0.0"
name : "HelloWorld"
displayName : "HelloWorld"
description: "Sample API"
version: "1.0.0"
serviceUrl: "https://localhost:8290/sample"
definitionType: "OAS3"
securityType: "BASIC"
mutualSSLEnabled: false
```

- swagger.yaml file

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: HelloWorld
  description: API Definition of HelloWorld
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /sample
paths:
  /testing:
    get:
      responses:
        default:
          description: Default response
```

- and my API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sample" name="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/testing">
        <inSequence/>
        <outSequence>
            <payloadFactory description="name" media-type="json">
                <format>
                 {"name":"$1","role":"$2"}
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.name"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.role"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Hope Someone can help me as I'm really stuck**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to the testing through the console included in APIM, it might  not recognize the Ingress host names (I assume the ingress host mapping is done in your local `/etc/hosts`). This should work if you use get the relevant curl and invoke it through the terminal.

As an alternative, you can use the service name (instead of Ingress host name) of the MI deployment and see whether you can invoke it through APIM's inbuilt console. This is of course if you have deployed those in the same namespace.

Comment: After some research I discovered that the service itself is still running on Integration studio's micro integrator instead of the Micro Integrator I deployed on kubernetes, I guess my problem now is running it there